# Why do I get "symbol not defined" error for 32-bit register names?

Tags: assembly, masm32

When I try to assemble this using masm32, I get a "symbol not defined" error for each line (beginning with `MOV EAX, 05h`) where 32-bit register names are used (lines 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12). Why is this? The command I use to assemble it is `ml.exe /Zm /Bl link.exe filepath\filename`

If I remove the `/Zm`switch, I still get an error at the same lines, only in this case, it is `"Instruction or register not accepted in current CPU-mode"`

The full and complete code:

```
code SEGMENT
MOV AX, 05h ;MOV B8+
MOV EAX, 05h
MOV BX, 06h
MOV EBX, 06h
MOV CX, 07h
MOV DX, 08h
MOV CR0, EAX ; 0F 22 /r
MOV CR0, EBX
MOV CR0, ECX
MOV CR0, EDX
MOV CR0, ESP
code ENDS
END
```

Note: The purpose of the code is to see what op-codes different instructions are translated into.

Comment: Maybe you are telling it it is 8086 instructions. What happens if you use `.686` directive at the top of your code?

Comment: If you showed your entire assembler file it might be give us more to go on.

Comment: Something else that is hard to tell is if you should be using the `/Zm` option that makes you compatible with an older version of MASM. Is there a reason you are using `/Zm`?

Comment: I took your code code, used MASM32, compiled it with /Zm and got errors on all the 32-bit registers. When I added `.686` to the top of the file those errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually shown us all of your code.  I strongly suspect that you are sending a directive at the beginning that is telling it that you want to generate 16 bit code.  The 32 bit registers, obviously, aren't available in 16 bit mode, so MASM is complaining.

Try inserting a `.386`, `.486`, `.586` or `.686` at the top of your assembly code.  You can find more information [here in the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use .386 at the top of your code 
let me give you simple example

```
.386
.model flate,c
.stack 100h
.data 
.code

main proc

mov eax,2

mov ebx,3

mul ebx
add eax,30h
mov ah,2

mov dl,eax
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h


main endp
end main
```